# c# Add Specific columns from a TEXT file to DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid

[image]

Hello Everyone,

As shown in the above image I want to add the decimal numbers column wise from a text file to datagrid control.

Following is my code snippet

```
List<string> str = new List<string>();
        String st = "";
        int k = 0;
        string[] s ;
        //Path to write contents to text file
        string filename = @"E:\Vivek\contentcopy\clientlist.txt";
        Form.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.FileName = "";

        ofd.ShowDialog();
        st = ofd.FileName;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ofd.FileName))
            return;
        string Name = "", No1 = "",No2="";
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(st).Where(sw => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sw)).ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {

            if (lines[i].Contains("VENTURA SECURITIES LIMITED (NSE F&O)")) continue;
            if (lines[i].Contains("ALL EXCHANGES DERIVATIVES CLIENTWISE STATEMENT AS ON 16-05-2012")) continue;
            if (lines[i].Contains("-------------------------------------------------------")) continue;
            s = lines[i].Split(' ');
            if (s[0] == "PARTY" || s[0] == "") continue;
            int z;
            Name = "";

            for (z = 1; z < s.Length; z++)
            {
                if (s[z] == "") continue;                    
                if (s[z].Contains('.'))
                {
                    No1+=s[z]+" ";
                    No2 = No1 + " ";  

                } 
                else
                {
                    Name += s[z];
                    str.Add(s[0]+"  "+Name);

                }



            }

            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[k].Cells[0].Value = s[0];
            dataGridView1.Rows[k].Cells[1].Value = Name;
            dataGridView1.Rows[k].Cells[2].Value = No1;
            dataGridView1.Rows[k].Cells[3].Value =  No2;
            k++;
        }


        File.WriteAllLines(filename, str);
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
    }
```

The line No1=s[z] directly takes the last column values ie 46,123.19 and so on.I want to fetch each column from the text file and store it in a string variable and then assign it to the datagrid view
I hope my doubt is clear.If not please let me know

Comment: And what exactly is not working? Are you getting errors or are the values not showing?

Comment: @DionV. Thanks for replying.Actually when I assign no1=s[z] it directly takes the last column ie 

46,123.19
1,990.20  and son on

I want that each column be assigned to a variable say 1st Column with values

200.0
0.0

Answer (score 3):

Here is the simplest Solution:

Add a DataGrid View to Form and add a Button:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReadAndFileter();
    }
    private void ReadAndFileter()
    {
        try
        {
            using(System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader("file.txt"))
            {
                string line;
                string []array;
                int rowcount= 0;
                decimal number;
                string[] separators = { "\t", " " };
                int columnCount = 0;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                   array = line.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 
                   dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                   foreach  (string str in array)
                   {

                       if (Decimal.TryParse(str,out number))
                       {
                           dataGridView1.Rows[rowcount].Cells[columnCount++].Value = number;                               
                       }                           
                   }
                   rowcount++;
                   columnCount = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

The File Contents are:

```
Abc         20.122      69.33   0.00        693.25  0.00
def         36.20       96.20   1.15        69.56   8.96
```

And the final output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Daredevil  ,I have updated and added full code ,can you help me with my code?

Comment: @user2614235 : what sort of help you need buddy?

Comment: I have added my complete code ..would you help me load contents to the DataGridView by suggesting changes to my code?

Comment: This is exactly what I was suggesting. :)

Answer (score 2):

Lets say, you have for lines in your test file, then u need to do following things:

1. Use StreamReader.ReadLine(), to read one line at time.
2. Spilt the line using split(' ') and store it in a array
3. Remove all the empty ones from the array
4. Now at index 2,3,4,5,6 of the resulting array will have the string equivalent of the decimal numbers.
5. Repeat this for each StreamReader.ReadLine()

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for the help.But I have done all the above step.I guess I am unable to do step number 4 and 5

Comment: string filename = @"E:\Vivek\contentcopy\clientlist.txt";
            Form.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.FileName = "";
            
            ofd.ShowDialog();
            st = ofd.FileName;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ofd.FileName))
                return;
            string Name = "", No1 = "",No2="";
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(st).Where(sw => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sw)).ToArray();

Comment: This seems to be perfect. Just iterate thru your final array and get the values.

Comment: I am new to c#

which array to iterate..can you give a code snippet to achieve the same

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are overwriting `No1` every time you read a string, which explains why you only get the last value. What you could do is either;

Append the string:

```
   No1 += s[z] + " ";
```

Which will put all the values behind eachother, seperated by a whitespace.

Or, you could make a `List<String>` and add each value to the list, meaning you have them stored seperated:

```
   List<String> values = new List<String>();
   foreach(...)
   {
      if (s[z] == "") continue;                    
      if (s[z].Contains('.'))
      {
            values.Add(s[z])
      } 
      else
      {
             Name += s[z];
             str.Add(s[0] + "  " + Name);
      }
   }
```

You can thereafter loop through the list and add each value to a row. Considering your code piece;

```
int i = 2;
foreach(string value in values)
{
   dataGridView1.Rows[k].Cells[i].Value = value;
   i++;
}
```

This should work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks But how to add these values separately to each columns on datagrid

ie datagried1.rows[i].column[0].value=?

Comment: Well, if you took the list option and considering your code piece that would be a simple foreach loop. I will add it to the answer since the code piece would become too big for a comment.

Comment: V.Its throwing arguments out of range exception

Comment: dataGridView1.Rows[k].Cells[i].Value = value; here

Answer (score 1):

Here is edited code: but for future I must suggest to give a try at least..

```
private void ReadAndFileter1()
    {
        try
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader("file.txt"))
            {
                string line;
                string[] array;
                int rowcount = 0;
                decimal number;
                string[] separators = { "\t", " " };
                int columnCount = 1;
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt");
                for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (lines[i].Contains("VENTURA SECURITIES LIMITED (NSE F&O)")) continue;
                    if (lines[i].Contains("ALL EXCHANGES DERIVATIVES CLIENTWISE STATEMENT AS ON 16-05-2012")) continue;
                    if (lines[i].Contains("-------------------------------------------------------")) continue;

                    array = lines[i].Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    if (array[0] == "PARTY" || array[0] == "") continue;

                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                    foreach (string str in array)
                    {
                        if (Decimal.TryParse(str, out number))
                        {
                            dataGridView1.Rows[rowcount].Cells[columnCount++].Value = number;
                        }
                    }
                    dataGridView1.Rows[rowcount].Cells[0].Value = array[0];
                    rowcount++;
                    columnCount = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Grid's Columns]

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Decimal result;
        string[] splitchar = new string[]{" "};

        using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\input.txt"))
        {
            while(!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] splittedArray = reader.ReadLine().Split(splitchar,                      StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(x => Decimal.TryParse(x, out result)).ToArray();

                // put your code here to get insert the values in datagrid
            }
        }

    }
```